# Let f be n-times differentiable and $f^{(n)}(x) \neq 0$. If $f^{(n)}$ has k zeroes, and show that f has at most n+k zeroes

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

I know this is a possible duplicate, but I'm really stuck on proving by induction. I'm trying to prove that if $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is n-times differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$, and assuming $f^{(n)} (x) \neq 0 \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$, then f has at most n zeros in $\mathbb{R}$.

For the base case, I was given the hint to use rolle's theorem. And so I have:

For k=1, we have $f'(x) \neq 0 \forall x$. And by Rolle's theorem, we know that $\exists x \in \mathbb{R} s.t f'(x) = 0$. And so for k=1, we have that f'(x) has at most 1 zero.

Now for the inductive hypothesis, we assume that $f^{(n)} (x)$ has at most n zeroes. We want to show that $f^{(n+1)} (x)$ has at most n+1 zeroes. I'm really stuck on this part. Help or a hint would be really really much appreciated.

Comment: Hint: If f has at least n distinct roots, then f' has at least n-1 distinct roots. This can be proven by mean value theorem. Say the roots are a_i, i=1,2,...,n. between a_i,a_{i+1}, you have b_i such that f'(b_i)=0 and the b_i the get are distinct

Comment: @Ben Oh I think I understand now! Rolle's theorem tells us we can find distinct $b_i$ between every $a_i and a_{i+1}$, and if we do this for all i=n, this naturally gives us n-1 distinct roots